# Using the broadcast reciever in android to handle incoming SMS messages

Tags: android

So i'm trying to handle incoming sms messages within an activity with a
BroadCastReciever as so:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
    BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                Log.i("SMSRECEIVER", "SMS RECIEVED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
            Log.i("SMSRECEIVER", "Something happened?");
        }
    };
    };
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter());
}
```

However It doesn't do anything (upon an inc sms message).

Also note that I do in fact have android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS as a
permission in my manifest.

Edit: Still not doing anything.

Comment: use `equals` instead of `==` for comparing Strings

Answer (score 0):

based on ρяσѕρєя K comment, you should put it like this and use Log instead of system.out.println :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
    Log.i("My Tag","SMS RECIEVED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  }
  Log.i("My Tag","Something happened?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try to use this SmsListener Receiver:

```
public class SmsListenerManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           
            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null) {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        System.out.println(msgBody+" <<< Message Body");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Add this to your manifest:**

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Under application tag :

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsListenerManager">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I hope it helps. Thanks